# prevent the duplicate of append and replace with pervious one

Tags: jquery, onclick, append

I have one append function like below:-

```js
function solve() {
var equ = $('#equ').val();
var names = equ.match(/[a-zA-z]/g).join("");
var list = $("#names-list");
var parent = list.parent();
list.detach().empty().each(function(i){
    for (var x = 0; x < names.length; x++){
        var one = $("#demo").append('<input type="radio" id="radio" name="demo" value="'+names[x]+'">'+names[x]);
        if (x == names.length - 1){
            $(this).appendTo(parent);
            
        }
    }
});
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="10x-3y+9t=0" id="equ"><button onclick="solve()">append</button>
<div id="parent"> <ul id="names-list"></ul></div>
<p id="demo" ></p>
```

when click the append button values are present successfully and click with second time same values are duplicated.how to stop the duplicated values and also before click the append button clear the previously displayed values in `demo` id.please correct my code to help solve my problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `append` or `appendTo` is use when you want to insert elements. If you want to append only once then you should use `html()` method of jQuery. Below is code.

```js
function solve() {
var equ = $('#equ').val();
var names = equ.match(/[a-zA-z]/g).join("");
var list = $("#names-list");
var parent = list.parent();
list.detach().empty().each(function(i){
    for (var x = 0; x < names.length; x++){
        var one = $("#demo").append('<input type="radio" id="radio" name="demo" value="'+names[x]+'">'+names[x]);
        if (x == names.length - 1){
            $(this).html(parent);
            
        }
    }
});
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="10x-3y+9t=0" id="equ"><button onclick="solve()">append</button>
<div id="parent"> <ul id="names-list"></ul></div>
<p id="demo" ></p>
```